# HTML anchor tag link format

Tags: php, html

In my PHP application, I'm controlling all the pages from one single PHP file.

e.g:-This is in my index.php file

```
switch (@$_GET['page'])
{
    case "addUser":
        require './add_user.php';
        break;
    case "addOrder":
        require './add_order.php';
        break;
    case "report":
        require './report.php';
        break;
    default:
        require './dashboard.php';
        break;
}
```

Since I'm doing this in a single page I do not need to specify the page in my anchor tag links (Since the application will be redirected to index.php anyway).

So, whenever I want to make a link to the add_user.php page, this is what I do.

```
<a href="?page=addUser">Add User</a>
```

So when a user click on this, he will be shown the add user page through index page. Just want to know if this is a correct way of doing this. Will this effect my application in future? Will this have any drawbacks?

Comment: Not sure this question is the right format for StackOverflow -- in general it will work, but it's not-standard practice. Normal links are a pretty good way to do things, then you can use includes within them.

Comment: I feel this question would be more fitting on [codereview.se]. But, please take a look at the Help Center (and possibly the Meta) before asking.

Comment: I'm doing this since I will not want to write a different .htaccess to hide the page extension part. Just wanted to know if it is a good practice and if it's not, what will be the issue that I will face in future.

Comment: Could be wrong, but I feel like this is on a track similar to how a MVC framework with a front controller is implemented. Check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648617.aspx) reference to see if it is inline with what you're looking for. You could use rewrite rules to rewrite a url for example `some-domain.com/dir1/page` to `some-domain.com?dir=dir1&page=page`. This would allow you to have cleaner slugs but handle the page loads as you currently do. Your current code would in essence become a front controller.

Comment: using `@` to suppress errors is bad practice. can't use it nicely with a `switch`, but in general, using `@` will just lead to trouble later on when you really do get an error, and are telling php to shut up about it. it's the coding equivalent of stuffing your fingers in your ears and going "lalalalala can't hear you"